# how to have image in css file that is loaded in a twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

in twig template I use this for image:

```
{% image '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

and this for css:

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

But in my css I have some classes with image:

```
background-image: url(../images/left_menu_bg.jpg);
```

Of course the image is broken, Is there any way to solve this? or I need to move the background image to twig template any way? if yes how can I have a background imgae for div?

```
<div class="blah" background="image.jpg">
```

I don't think full path like:

```
background-image: url(Acme/AcmeDemo/images/left_menu_bg.jpg);
```

will help because of query parameters in URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the cssrewrite filter inside your stylesheets tag :

From the symfony doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-including-css

> But because Assetic changes the paths to your assets, this will break
>   any background images (or other paths) that uses relative paths,
>   unless you use the cssrewrite filter.

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/acme_foo/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I did that. Css file itself is loaded now but the backgroung images on css file still are not shown. How the image path should be in css files?